# Error on warm reboot, not on cold boot

Tags: linux, windows, boot, reboot, xeon

Every time I boot my computer from the power-off state, it works fine (cold boot).  However, whenever I reboot the machine (ex: shutdown /r) it will hang on the next boot-up.  This problem has been around since I built the machine and it is the same on Windows 7 and Windows 10 and various flavors of Linux.  It will wake up from sleep ok, but won't successfully warm-reboot.

Probably unrelated: the screens of this machine never go to low power mode.

I've tried messing with bios settings many times to try to keep everything as conservative as possible.  It has never been overclocked.

What could be causing this machine to fail on warm-reboot?  What might I do to further trouble-shoot it?

Hardware:

```
Xeon E3-1225 v2 (3.2GHz)
MSI Z77A-G41
Radeon R7 200 Series
20 GB DDR3
```

Comment: Do you have any USB storage devices plugged in?  Try removing those if so.   What stage does it hang?

Comment: There's no usb storage attached.  There is 1 usb speaker, 1 usb keyboard, 1 usb mouse.  There are two SSDs and one spinning disk attached (SATA).  During a windows boot, it blue screens some time into loading drivers before login screen.

Comment: I just have a similar problem: if I make a reboot it crashes during the firmware loading, and if I call poweroff,... it performs a successfull cold reboot. I happens since I tried to set efi variables from linux while the secure boot was in set up mode. I suppose I have corrupted the bios, or some hidden variable in the NVRAM.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer!

After replacing the video card, I noticed that reboots started working again.
I went back to the old card and, sure enough, it was unable to properly reboot under windows.

I'm guessing this was a hardware issue with that particular card.

Comment: For future reference, check the event logs in the OS.  I would suspect there would be entries related to the graphics card.  Obviously, check to make sure the card has the latest drivers and if possible, the latest BIOS/firmware.